# How do I get the sway bar link to line up with new strut and spring?

Tags: toyota, suspension, sienna

I am swapping the struts and sway bar links on a 2006 Toyota Sienna AWD.

I got the first strut in place and started to put the sway bar link on but it does not want to line up with the mounting hole on the new strut. It looks like the link is about 2 inches too long, but I compared with the old link and they are the same length.

Does the car need to be level before this lines up? Or should I put the wheel back on and take the van off the jack / jack stand for this to line up?

What is the correct procedure?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: do you have another jack that you could use to jack up your a-arm a bit to change the triangulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bar will fit best with the suspension in it's normal rest position, i.e. if the car is sitting on it's wheels. As DucatiKiller says in his comment, the best method is to jack up the hubs (making sure to put the jacks under a solid casting, so they can't cause any damage to the brakes!) to simulate the normal position.

Comment: Ok cool will try it tomorrow